# Please ID a weird vine, a pseudo hybrid of these two varieties

Tags: identification, indoors, succulents, vines

I met a lady that had a vine similar to a variegated pothos or a philodendron, with very fat and succulent heart-shaped leaves, about 4-5 millimetres thickness, 4"/10cm long, hanging on water-filled stems about 4mm across. It was a very succulent dark green shade loving vine. The lady told me that she had it for ages and it was an easy plant.

Can you think of a plant that is like a hybrid of these two varieties? The nearest I have found is Scindapsus/Photos except with very fat leaves.

[image] [image]

Comment: Which picture is the plant you want to identify?

Comment: I don't have a photo of the plant to ID, it has the leaf shape of the first photo and leaves even fatter than the second. It's a dark green variagated vine with large heart leaves of a succulent variety.

Comment: See if any of these are similar. Hoya kerrii,  Ceropegia woodii, and especially Epipremnum aureum "snow queen".

Comment: Did it climb? or hang down?

Comment: Thanks! It's very similar to Epipremnum aureum "snow queen" the only difference being is tha the leaves look like cusions when seen sideways, they are 4-5 mm and very pithy. In every other way it's the same. The stems all hang down and the leaves go straight sideways and flat. I actually found those suggestions in a 30 minute web search prior to posting the question. it's a rather uncommon variety.

Comment: @Polypipe Wrangler Perhaps it's an exotic Caropegia, i.e. Ceropegia Rupiclola or a hybrid, i.e. this, although the leaves are still too thin, it had huge cushion leaves. https://picclick.co.uk/60cm-Miniature-Variegated-Foliage-CEROPEGIA-Creeper-Hanging-Dollhouse-164218473909.html